# How to use website selectmenu in C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a website where there is 4 columns where the user can select from a Selectmenu where there is 4 items of data in each column.

I have a button and when the user clicks on it, I would like to write our what the user selected in the columns (`MyButton_Click`). I tried a lot of ways but I do not find out how can I use the values in my program because I get an error:

> CS0103 - The name 'Column1' does not exist in the current context in (MyButton_Click) code.

Can somebody help me how can I use the result of the columns in my code and point it out?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CarDatas.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.CarDatas" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Car Datas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        h2 {
            color: #333;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .date-input, .column-input {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 8px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        .calendar {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            z-index: 1000;
        }
        .custom-button {
            width: 200px; 
            height: 40px; 
            margin-top: 10px; 
            margin-bottom: 10px; 
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".date-input").datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    $(this).val(dateText);
                    $(".calendar").hide();
                }
            });

            var columnOptions = '<option value=""></option>'; 
            columnOptions +=
                '<option value="make">Make</option>' +
                '<option value="_owner">Owner</option>' +
                '<option value="center">Center</option>' +
                '<option value="subsidiary">Subsidiary</option>';

            $(".column-input").html(columnOptions);
        });

        function showCalendar(dateTextBoxId, calendarId) {
            var dateTextBox = $("#" + dateTextBoxId);
            var calendar = $("#" + calendarId);

            var rect = dateTextBox.offset();
            calendar.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: rect.left + 'px',
                top: rect.top + dateTextBox.outerHeight() + 'px'
            });

            if (calendar.is(":hidden")) {
                $(".calendar").hide();
                calendar.show();
            } else {
                calendar.hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Date and Columns Selection</h2>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <label for="DateFromTextBox">Date From:</label>
        <input type="text" id="DateFromTextBox" class="date-input" onclick="showCalendar('DateFromTextBox', 'Calendar1')">
        <div id="Calendar1" class="calendar"></div>

        <label for="DateToTextBox">Date To:</label>
        <input type="text" id="DateToTextBox" class="date-input" onclick="showCalendar('DateToTextBox', 'Calendar2')">
        <div id="Calendar2" class="calendar"></div>

        <label for="Column1">Column 1:</label>
        <select id="Column1" class="column-input"></select>

        <label for="Column2">Column 2:</label>
        <select id="Column2" class="column-input"></select>

        <label for="Column3">Column 3:</label>
        <select id="Column3" class="column-input"></select>

        <label for="Column4">Column 4:</label>
        <select id="Column4" class="column-input"></select>

        <br>
        <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="MyButton_Click" CssClass="custom-button" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class CarDatas : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedValueColumn1 = Column1.SelectedValue;
            string selectedValueColumn2 = Column2.SelectedValue;
            string selectedValueColumn3 = Column3.SelectedValue;
            string selectedValueColumn4 = Column4.SelectedValue;

            Response.Write($"Selected values: {selectedValueColumn1}, {selectedValueColumn2}, {selectedValueColumn3}, {selectedValueColumn4}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to do some basic Webform tutorials first and learn how Controls work...

Answer (score 0):

This question can be easily solved by using ChatGPT (the free version is good enough), but since you asked here, I would like to share my 2 cents:

According to this:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValueColumn1 = Column1.SelectedValue;
    string selectedValueColumn2 = Column2.SelectedValue;
    string selectedValueColumn3 = Column3.SelectedValue;
    string selectedValueColumn4 = Column4.SelectedValue;

    Response.Write($"Selected values: {selectedValueColumn1}, {selectedValueColumn2}, {selectedValueColumn3}, {selectedValueColumn4}");
}
```

You're trying to get the values from the 4 "SELECT" "Columns", but since you're not using ASP.NET Server controls (runat="server"), you're using plain HTML inputs, you need to assign the attribute "name" to each "input", in your case, the "SELECT" tag.

Assigning attribute "name" is a very basic concept and fundamental of HTML coding, which I think you haven't gone through a proper basic HTML tutorial. It's ok, not a big problem with that. I'm just pointing it out that you have missed the fundamental concept of HTML coding.

At this block:

```
<label for="Column1">Column 1:</label>
<select id="Column1" class="column-input"></select>

<label for="Column2">Column 2:</label>
<select id="Column2" class="column-input"></select>

<label for="Column3">Column 3:</label>
<select id="Column3" class="column-input"></select>

<label for="Column4">Column 4:</label>
<select id="Column4" class="column-input"></select>
```

Add the attribute of "name" to the "Select" tag, all HTML inputs ("SELECT" is one of the input) require the attribute of "name" for a POST request. Therefore, after adding the attribute of "name", it will look something like this:

```
<label for="Column1">Column 1:</label>
<select name="myform-column1" id="Column1" class="column-input"></select>

<label for="Column2">Column 2:</label>
<select name="myform-column2" id="Column2" class="column-input"></select>

<label for="Column3">Column 3:</label>
<select name="myform-column3" id="Column3" class="column-input"></select>

<label for="Column4">Column 4:</label>
<select name="myform-column4" id="Column4" class="column-input"></select>
```

Then, at your code behind, you can obtain the values like this:

```
string selectedValueColumn1 = Request["myform-column1"] + "";
string selectedValueColumn2 = Request["myform-column2"] + "";
string selectedValueColumn3 = Request["myform-column3"] + "";
string selectedValueColumn4 = Request["myform-column4"] + "";
```